# How do I add a route without affecting Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, html.actionlink

My routes :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //Add a custom Route that implements IRouteHandler
        Route metadata = new Route("metadata", new MetadataRoute());
        routes.Add("Metadata",  metadata);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My view : 
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")

The desired client html : 
    href="/"

The actual client html : 
    href="/metadata?action=Index&controller=Home"

Is there a way to get Html.ActionLink to disregard the metadata route?

Thanks

Comment: What is `MetadataRoute`?

Comment: MetadataRoute is an IRouteHandler that returns a IHttpHandler

Answer (score 0):

I found this 
[Custom IRouteHandler route screws up MVC link building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351415/custom-iroutehandler-route-screws-up-mvc-link-building)
Its not a graceful solution but it actually worked. I was shocked.